# Use value of a column for another column (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

lets say I have a huge select on a certain table. One value for a column is calculated with complex logc and its called *ColumnA*. Now, for another column, I need the value from *ColumnA* and add some other static value to it.

Sample SQL:

```
select table.id, table.number, complex stuff [ColumnA], [ColumnA] + 10 .. from table ...
```

The *[ColumnA] + 10* is what im looking for. The complex stuff is a huge case/when block.

Ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to reference a value that's computed in the `SELECT` clause, you need to move the existing query into a sub-SELECT:

```
SELECT
    /* Other columns */,
    ColumnA,
    ColumnA + 10 as ColumnB
FROM
(select table.id, table.number, complex stuff [ColumnA].. from table ...
) t
```

You have to introduce an alias for this table (in the above, `t`, after the closing bracket) even if you're not going to use it.

(Equivalently - assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or later - you can move your existing query into a CTE):

```
;WITH PartialResults as (
     select table.id, table.number, complex stuff [ColumnA].. from table ...
)
SELECT /* other columns */, ColumnA, ColumnA+10 as ColumnB from PartialResults
```

CTEs tend to look cleaner if you've got multiple levels of partial computations being done, I.e. if you've now got a calculation that depends on ColumnB to include in your query.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT 3 AS a, 6/a AS b;
```

Error: Invalid column name: 'a'.

Comment: You can use a cte for this: WITH cte AS (SELECT 3 AS a) SELECT a, 6/a AS b FROM cte;

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with **a subquery and column aliases**.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT MaxId + 10
FROM (SELECT Max(t.Id) As MaxId
      FROM SomeTable t) As SomeTableMaxId
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Do the `+ 10` in the client code
2. Write a scalar-valued function to encapsulate the logic for `complex stuff`. It will be optimized into a single call.
3. Copy `complex stuff` logic for the other column. It should get optimized out into 1 call.
4. Use a sub-select to apply the additional calculation

Answer (score 1):

One convenient option to reuse scalar expressions in a query is to use `APPLY` (or `LATERAL` in standard SQL):

```sql
SELECT
  table.id,
  table.number,
  [ColumnA],
  [ColumnA] + 10
FROM 
  table
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT complex stuff [ColumnA]) t
```