# SQL SELECT statement expression value reuse for other expression

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with huge row count in mysql (though I am looking for generic SQL solution)

```
very_big_table(INT a, INT b, INT c, ...)
```

I wanted SELECT statement

```
SELECT a, 
    (b + c) as expression1,
    (b + c + a) AS expression2 -- basically (expression1 + a)
FROM very_big_table
WHERE ...
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a DESC
```

this looks good and easily readable as long as the expression1 is simple.
But when CASE-WHEN/IFNULL()/SUM()/MIN()/STRCAT() or some Operator comes into play in these expressions its difficult to read and debug.

I have gone through some of the already asked questions
[assigning mysql value to variable inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623410/assigning-mysql-value-to-variable-inline)
[Use value of a column for another column (SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180979/use-value-of-a-column-for-another-column-sql-server)
[How to use conditional columns values in the same select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790697/how-to-use-conditional-columns-values-in-the-same-select-statement)

But if I use the approaches described something like

```
SELECT a, 
    expression1,
    (expression1 + a) AS expression2
FROM 
    (SELECT a,
        (b + c) AS expression1
    FROM very_big_table
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY a) as inner_table
ORDER BY a DESC
```

this works fine, but this query is taking some 70x more time to execute. Atleast when i fired it, though only once.
what if I have multiple levels of the *expressions* in the output columns?

Is there any elegant way to deal with this, without compromising readability?

BTW why isnt this *expression reuse* or *alias reference* in select statement not supported by SQL standards or vendors? (supposing there are no cyclic evaluation in the single SELECT statement expressions. in that case the compiler fails)

Comment: Why do you think that being able to reuse the expression alias will lead to a 70x reduction in execution time? Can you show a real example with real queries and the .sqlplan files for an actual execution plan? I can almost guarantee that such a disparity in execution time is not due to adding a subquery - something else must be different.

Comment: @Quail still can't envision a scenario where that's the only difference and it leads to a 70x performance difference.

Comment: I deleted my comment after Aaron edited his. For posterity it said, "I imagine he's comparing it specifying every column explicity."

Comment: As for the why, let's not re-hash this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19762/why-is-the-select-clause-listed-first http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in

Comment: Has this very big table got a primary key and what is it?

Answer (score 8):

You can use User-Defined Variable to solve your problem. Your SQL can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT a, 
    @expr1 := (b + c) as expression1,
    (@expr1 + a) AS expression2
FROM very_big_table
WHERE ...
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a DESC
```

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32894065/1393498).

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 choices for that..

using your actual query as a subquery

```
 select a,exp1,exp1+a as exp2
 from (SELECT a 
             ,(b + c) as exp1
       FROM very_big_table
       WHERE ...
       GROUP BY a
 )V
 ORDER BY a DESC
```

or adding a outer apply statment for your query...

```
SELECT a 
      ,OA.exp1 as expression1
      ,(OA.exp1 + a) AS expression2 -- basically (expression1 + a)
FROM very_big_table
outer apply (select (b + c) as exp1) OA
WHERE ...
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a DESC
```

I guess the second option, using outer apply, is better for read...

keep in mind that Outer apply runs for each row

so it may be a bad idea if the exp1 have to access large amounth of data from tables..

anyway, just using fields that you are already getting in your actual query
you will not have a great cost by adding it.

so.. what way you would choose?

Comment: Why `outer apply` and not `cross apply`?

Answer (score 0):

workaround assuming that the expressions are not sql select sub-clauses, but rather nested operators/functions purely acting on data retrieved in the original "select from" clause so the task at hand is purely and simply to make the code "look pretty":
create user-defined-functions

then your query would look like

```
select a
, myfunction( b, c)
, myfunction( b, c) + a
...
```

upside -this cleans up the "select code" which was your stated goal, also you can centrally manage more complex logic

downside - this is not "generic sql" that will port to other systems and maybe not worth the investment in time if the functions will rarely be re-used

Answer (score 0):

For Postgresql users

If you want to maximize readibility of the complex computation and/or logic, encapsulate the computation in its own function

```
create table x
(
    a int not null,
    b int not null,
    c int not null
);

create table y
(
    a int not null,
    z int not null
);


select * from x;

insert into x VALUES
(1,2,3), (4,5,6);

insert into y values
(1, 100);
```

#### Function with complex computation and/or logic:

```
create or replace function computer
(
    rx x, -- this emphasizes that the source of data come from table x
    ry y, -- this emphasizes that the source of data come from table x

    out expression1 int, out expression2 int, out expression3 int
)
as $$
begin
    expression1 := rx.b + rx.c;
    expression2 := expression1 + rx.a;
    expression3 := expression2 + ry.z;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Test query:

```
select x.a, x.b, x.c, y.z, answer.*
from x
join y on x.a = y.a
cross join lateral computer(x,y) answer
```

Output:

[image]

If you just need to quickly test the function's returned values, it can be expanded by using parenthesis-asterisk syntax:

```
select x.a, x.b, x.c, y.z, (computer(x, y)).*
from x
join y on x.a = y.a
```

Don't use that in production though, if the function has 50 returned columns, the function will be called 50 times. Use `cross join lateral` in production. See: [How can you expand a "condensed" PostgreSQL row into separate columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444008/how-can-you-expand-a-condensed-postgresql-row-into-separate-columns/24444348#24444348)

If your function don't need to concern itself where the data source come from, just use the `record` type on function's parameter

```
create or replace function computer_b
(
    anon record,
    out expression1 int, out expression2 int, out expression3 int
)
as $$
begin
    expression1 := anon.b + anon.c;
    expression2 := expression1 + anon.a;
    expression3 := expression2 + anon.z;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Test query:

```
with data_source as
(
    select x.*, y.z
    from x
    join y on x.a = y.a
)
select ds.*, answer.*
from data_source ds
cross join lateral computer_b(ds) answer
```